# Autofill for a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a user defined function under module folder in VB Editor. The function calculates the values for each cell in F column by performing around 20 If conditions based on the combination of values present in C column, D column and E column.

The function returns the calculated value when I include the function as a formula in F1 cell (i.e. =calculateValue()). The function takes no input parameters. Based on the active row, it calculates the value and returns.

But the autofill statement I have written does not populate the value for other cells of F column when I double click the F1 cell (after having invoked the user defined function). It copies the same value as in F1 to the rest of the cells of F column. It seems other cells of F column are not taking their respective active row into considering when invoking the function.

```
Set targetRange = Range(StartRange, StartRange.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))
Range("F1").AutoFill Destination:=targetRange
```

Comment: Use a ***Sub*** rather than a ***UDF()***

Comment: Will I be able to invoke sub just like function from a cell within excel? Would it solve the problem that I'm facing? I'm new to VBA programming. Please help

Comment: Unless the *UDF()* returns an **array**, it can only return a **single** value to a **single** cell.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Your UDF would work better if you passed in as parameters the values from column C, D and E rather than reading them directly from within the UDF.

```
=calculateValue(C1,D1,E1)
```

Then your UDF does not need to know what the active row is (which BTW won't change when you programatically do the fill anyway)